# Laravel 5.1 session not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, session

I was testing Laravel 5.1's session feature in WAMP, following those steps:

1. `composer create-proejct laravel/laravel laravel5.1 --prefer-dist`
2. in routes.php, I added `Route::get('/testsession', 'TestSessionController@index');`
3. in TestSessionController.php, I added the following:

;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;

class TestSessionController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        Session::set('aa', 'bb');
        var_dump(Session::get('aa'));
    }
}
```

I first run the application, and it outputted `string 'bb' (length=2)`. Then I commented `Session::set('aa', 'bb');` and run again, and it outputted null.

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
```

And then:

```
$value = Session::get('key');
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help!

I finally came across [this post](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/middleware-groups-in-laravel-5-2) and got it worked. The reason is that I was actually using 5.2, and I didn't release I was using this new release. Sorry for being misleading.

In Laravel 5.2, everything need to be given a web middleware in order to use cookies or sessions. It is not mentioned in [Laravel upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) though.